# What's the difference between "knowledge of sth" and "perception of sth "?

Tags: phrases, differences

In the following sentence

> Through the discussion they gained an extraordinary **insight into** the complexity of women's emotions.

I was asked to replace "insight of" with either "knowledge of" or "perception of". Could you please tell me what the difference is between the two phrases?

Comment: Can you tell us or link to the source of your sentence? The word 'experience' seems wrong.

Comment: @Shoe Sorry, it's a typo. Just deleted it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This site usually expects some evidence of your attempts to answer your own question, so it might be good to tell us why the definitions you have found of the three words have not led to an answer. Again, it would be useful to know the source of the sentence because _insight __of___ is less common than _insight __into___ in such contexts.

Comment: it's insight into something; not insight of. Not worth answering until that is changed/acknowledged. "Through the discussion, they gained extraordinary insight into the complexity of women's emotions".

Comment: @Lambie it is "insight into". I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> perception : the way you think about sth and your idea of what it is like.
>
> knowledge : the information, skills, and understanding you gain through learning or experience.

*These definitions are from Longman dictionary.*

So it can be understood that knowledge is more based on facts and reality; it is derived from studying and experiences.

Perception comes before knowledge. It does not have a necessarily concrete and reliable basis as it is derived from your own thoughts and ideas rather than learning and experience. Perception may lead to knowledge but not necessarily.  it can even lead in to the opposite.